# Nivo Slider Nivo-control Nav margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I have a site that has 4 subpages. I want to add nivo slider on each page in separate height. I've added 3 sliders successfully, but on one page I want to show `nivo-controlNav` with margin top 30px, how can I do that?

My code looks like this:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
text-align:center;
padding: 0;
}
```

It's good for my other 3 pages but I want to add:

```
.nivo-controlNav {
text-align:center;
padding: 0;
margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: So basically you want that margin-top to apply to only one of the four?

Comment: no other pager are designed for without margin top :(

Comment: whats the problem?  set the margin on that page for the slider to whatever you want? use inline css if you want to put margin on the particular page

Comment: actually ive try to to that but in nivo slider "nivo-controlNav" not display on HTML ... :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on the page wher u need margin  in < head >< / head > section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nivo-controlNav').css('margin','30px');

    });
</script>
```

if that doesnt help try setting z-index, visible properties like above
 $('.nivo-controlNav').css('z-index','1500');
 $('.nivo-controlNav').css('visibility','visible');

Comment: do you have firebug installed on mozila browser? this is to find out the class of the paging div

Comment: right click on the paging div and inspect element and get the class of the div (where paging/nav control is shown). let me know when you get the classname of the div. if not also comment back

Comment: now im using google web developer i think it can do that .. ive found class name called "nivo-controlNav" then..

Comment: then i think the code i gave you above should work.try adding the above code. set margins to whatever you want. you can try adding z-index or other css properties like  $('.nivo-controlNav').css('z-index','1500'); above

Answer (score 0):

You must add some class or id to separate from others. Then you write a style for that 
particular class or id or use the inline style (Inline is not a good practice)
for example

```
.classname
{
margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: this is my problem  there is no class name show in nivo slider ... "nivo-controlNav" shows like this .. in html .. if i view in google chrome its showing liks this "nivo-controlNav" ...

Answer (score 0):

If it is on a completely separate page you can easily just add the second set of rules you have above. If they are all governed by one single style sheet you can do this

```
   .differentClassName{
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nivo-controlNav {
text-align: center;
padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
clear:both;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;}
```